# sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command

Tags: unix, centos, command

When I run the command

```
sed -i.backup "/proxySettings['nginxCacheSize']/s/$/ . " inactive=5h"/"
```

I get the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unterminated `s' command

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's leave the `-i` flag out of this for now, and simplify the command a little:

```
sed "/'foo']/s/$/ "bar"/"
```

You have both single quotes and double quotes inside your expression, and `sed` is getting confused about where the command begins and ends. As written, it appears to be this:

```
sed "/'foo']/s/$/ "
```

(with some gibberish after it), which clearly has an unterminated `s` command. We could use single quotes instead of double quotes to demark the command, but then we'd have the same problem with the single quotes around `foof`. So we escape those internal double quotes with backslashes:

```
sed "/'foo']/s/$/ \"bar\"/"
```